# External screen detected but not working on DisplayPort connection

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, laptop, thinkpad, displayport

I'm running up to date Raring on my Thinkpad X220 and stumbled upon weird problem.

I can connect to an external 24 inch DELL U2312HM external screen using DisplayPort cable.

I tried the same connection at work, with similar, but larger screen - 27 inch DELL U2713HM using the same cable.

When I check `>>Settings >> Displays` the display is detected. However I'm looking at dark screen.. Bizarrely - when I hit the PrtScr - I can also see it correctly with Ubuntu walpaper o_O

The monitor is detected and works correctly when using [DisplayPort to DVI-D Adapter Cable (Single Link)](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow%3aitem.detail?GroupID=460&Code=45J7915&category-id=67FB3393C9474D4EBB539D3DC944B8CE&hide_menu_area=yes) however the resolution on this setup is limited to 1920 x 1200 so I'd really like to take advantage of DVI since the laptop [should support it](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/What-resolution-for-external-monitor-with-X220/td-p/608781).

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Posted also on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2149238&p=12666739#post12666739

Comment: And: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/External-screen-detected-but-not-working-on-DVI-D-connection-on/td-p/1133381

Comment: And: http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=110177

Comment: Does your Thinkpad have NVidia Optimus technology?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel No, it's Intel HD 3000.